# WordPress API - count posts

Tags: api, wp-cli

Is there a way to count the number of posts / pages via the WordPress API?

I'm wanting to insert a post then check, using the API, that the count has gone up by 1.

I've looked at http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.getPosts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Linux or OS X, the easiest way is probably to use wp-cli (if present in your WordPress installation) to return a list of all posts:

```
wp-cli post list
```

Then pipe it to the word count tool to get the number of lines:

```
wc -l
```

Finally, deduct one to take care of the header line which is not a post:

```
awk '{print $1-1}'
```

So, in one line:

```
wp-cli post list | wc -l | awk '{print $1-1}'
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be some basic method in WP-CLI (e.g. like `wp-cli post count`) that did the job but this is very helpful - thanks.

Answer (score 6):

With WP-CLI installed from https://wp-cli.org/ you can retrieve the total post count by using:

`wp post list --format=count`

[Full documentation for the POST LIST command](https://wp-cli.org/commands/post/list/)